# Reflection between differents projects (assemblies)

Tags: c#, .net, reflection

Is there any way, from a given project, to create instances of classes contained in other projects ?

I usually use `Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CreateInstance()`, but obviously, this call will return NULL as the class I'm specifying is held in another project.

Any ideas ?

Comment: What's wrong with referencing the project?

Comment: I don't think Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CreateInstance() will  allow you to load objects from another project even if that project is being referenced in the executing project.

Comment: so you need a circular reference basically?

Comment: Not sure if that's fits the definition, but I need from my main project, to dynamically (using a string to specify the name of the object) enumerate all of a class's properties that's held in another project. I ended up using Assembly.LoadFrom().

Comment: @FrancisDucharme can you please post the solution for this? I too need to create a class dynamically and it's referencing a class in another project. It always returns null now.

Comment: @WebDevGuy This was a while ago. I think I just ended up referring the project. Can you post a question if that did not work for you ?

Comment: @WebDevGuy Actually, I used `Assembly.LoadFrom()` just as my previous comment pointed out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you really want to use reflection to achieve this then look at `Assembly.LoadFrom()`. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly.loadfrom.aspx
Alternatively, as someone pointed out, you can simply use project references.

Answer (score 1):

You can check out the .net activator methods http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.activator_methods.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You'll probably want to use Assembly.LoadFrom() to load the assembly from a file if you're trying to do reflection.

But if you simply want to use objects in the assembly, add the assembly as a reference to your project (right click the project in Solution Explorer, and click "Add Reference"). Then you can simlpy use all public objects from the referenced assembly.